# match optional pattern

Tags: node.js, regex

I have the string "x/path/to/file/400x0/image.jpg?v=asdf" where the "400x0" part is optional.

I would need the following matches for "x/path/to/file/400x0/image.jpg?v=asdf":

1. /path/to/file/
2. 400
3. 0
4. image.jpg

And the following matches for "x/path/to/file/image.jpg?v=asdf":

1. /path/to/file/
2. -
3. -
4. image.jpg

### What i have so far

`^(?:[^\/]+)(.*)\/(\d+)x(\d+)\/([^\?]+)` This one works fine as long as there is the "400x0" part

### What i tried

I tried to define the numbers part as optional `^(?:[^\/]+)(.*)(?:\/(\d+)x(\d+))?\/([^\?]+)` but in this case it adds the "400x0" to the first match. It would work for "x/path/to/file/image.jpg?v=asdf"

I guess `?` is simply not the right operator?

https://regex101.com/r/8eYGyc/3

I am using node.js 8

Comment: See `^[^\/]+((?:\/(?!\d+x\d+)[^\/]+)*)(?:\/(\d+)x(\d+))?\/([^?]+)` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/RQ98xm/3). A bit safer version: `^[^\/]+((?:\/(?!\d+x\d+(?:\/|$))[^\/]+)*)(?:\/(\d+)x(\d+))?\/([^?]+)`

Comment: Thanks, thats it. I'll accept it if you make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest making the `.*` a bit more precise to only match chunks of `/` and then any 1+ chars other than `/` and restrict that latter part so that it could not match `\d+x\d+` subpart:

```
^[^\/]+((?:\/(?!\d+x\d+(?:\/|$))[^\/]+)*)(?:\/(\d+)x(\d+))?\/([^?]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HHG1JP/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `[^\/]+` - 1 or more chars other than `/`
- `((?:\/(?!\d+x\d+(?:\/|$))[^\/]+)*)` - Group 1: any zero or more repetitions of

  - `\/(?!\d+x\d+(?:\/|$))` - a `/` char that is not followed with `digits+x+digits` subpart (followed with `/` or end of string)
  - `[^\/]+` - 1 or more chars other than `/`
- `(?:\/(\d+)x(\d+))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `\/` - a `/` char
  - `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits
  - `x` - an `x` char
  - `(\d+)` - Group 3: one or more digits
- `\/` - a `/` char
- `([^?]+)` - Group 4: any 1 or more chars other than `?`.